# How to, extract specific information from a GLM summary table in Python

Tags: python, glm, statmodels

After ruuning a glm model by this Python code :

`mod1 = sm.GLM(response, predictors, family=sm.genmod.families.family.Gaussian()).fit()`

`print(mod1.summary())`

I got the following summary table :

[image]

I know how to extarct the coefficient, but I would like to extract other information, as the Log-Likehood value for example. How can I proceed ?

Comment: I haven't got any reply for this question. Coudl somebody help me ?